# How to make query in model with 2 parameters

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller, codeigniter-4

I need make a query with 2 parameters in model on codeigniter 4.
Is this possible?

This is the model:

```
public function obtenerProyectoId($id_user,$id_project)
{
    $proyectos = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM proyectos INNER JOIN empresa ON proyectos.id_usuario=$id_user and proyectos.id_proyecto=id_project");
    return $proyectos->getResultArray();
}
```

in mysql this query is correct, but in  CI4 it shows an error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Models\Proyectos::obtenerProyecto(),
> 1 passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\plataformaknowmad\app\Controllers\verProyectos.php on
> line 25 and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Can you show the code where you have created the instance of the the Model ?

Comment: Also you are passing the second parameter but doesn't seem to be used anywhere. $id_project

Comment: How do you call the model's function `obtenerProyectoId()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make a query with multiple params.

```
//if second param is optional
public function obtenerProyectoId($id_user,$id_project="")
```

In query $ is missing from id_project

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM proyectos INNER JOIN empresa ON proyectos.id_usuario=$id_user and proyectos.id_proyecto=$id_project");
```

May be you did not pass second parameter($id_project) in controller:

> verProyectos.php on line 25 and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Thanks, an undefined variable was used that was not getting to the model.